# Oracle SQL - 2 queries that join 3 tables and divide a list without overlap

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables

**Table 1** Is the list of users who qualify for this program
It has the CUSTOMER_ID field. This list has *multiple entries per user*, all of which need to be included in the final lists described below.

**Table 2** (b) is the list of most (but not all) users and the best times to contact them. It has the Fields:

- USER_ID
- MONDAY
- TUESDAY
- WEDNESDAY
- THURSDAY
- FRIDAY
- SATURDAY
- SUNDAY

**Table 3** is the Master List of all users that has the fields:

- USER_ID
- CUSTOMER_ID

I need to divide Table 1 into 2 lists:

**List 1** needs to be all users (and all rows per user) in Table 1 that:

- Have a value in todays field that is within a range in Table 2

(I.e. if Today is Monday include all users from Table 1 that have
   a value between 6 & 23 in the Monday field from Table 2)

This is what I have for list one which seems to work:

```
SELECT b.USER_ID, b.monday, b.tuesday, b.wednesday, b.thursday, 
b.friday, b.saturday, b.sunday FROM $A$ a, $C$ c, $B$ b 
WHERE ( 
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 1 AND (b.sunday >= 6 AND b.sunday <= 23) OR 
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 2 AND (b.monday >= 6 AND b.monday <= 23) OR 
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 3 AND (b.tuesday >= 6 AND b.tuesday <= 23) OR 
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 4 AND (b.wednesday >= 6 AND b.wednesday <= 23) OR 
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 5 AND (b.thursday >= 6 AND b.thursday <= 23) OR 
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 6 AND (b.friday >= 6 AND b.friday <= 23) OR 
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 7 AND (b.saturday >= 6 AND b.saturday <= 23) ) 
AND (c.USER_ID = b.USER_ID AND a.CUSTOMER_ID_ = c.CUSTOMER_ID_)
```

**List 2** should include all users (and all rows per user) in Table 1 who:

- Have a null value in today’s field in Table 2
- Have a value outside the range (I.e. not between 6 & 23)
- Are not in Table 2 at all

I have 2 queries for list 2 and I’m not sure how to combine them.

The record counts I am getting on these 3 queries combined are more than the original list so there is definitely some overlap going on.

Can anyone offer insight on how I can write this second query?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including the DDL statements for your tables, DML statements for example data that illustrates the issue and your expected output for that sample data.

Comment: If you run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'DENMARK';` (or many, many other territories) then `TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'D' )` will output 1 if today is Monday and not Sunday as per your example and your query will not give the output you are expecting. A better solution would be to use `TRUNC( sysdate ) - TRUNC( sysdate, 'IW' )` as this is independent of the NLS settings (Monday = 0 ... Sunday = 6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9ed5f/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( CUSTOMER_ID ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  USER_ID,
  MONDAY,
  TUESDAY,
  WEDNESDAY,
  THURSDAY,
  FRIDAY,
  SATURDAY,
  SUNDAY
) AS
SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table3 ( USER_ID, CUSTOMER_ID ) As
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT b.USER_ID, 
       b.monday,
       b.tuesday,
       b.wednesday,
       b.thursday, 
       b.friday,
       b.saturday,
       b.sunday
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN table3 c
       ON ( a.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID )
       INNER JOIN table2 b 
       ON ( c.USER_ID = b.USER_ID )
WHERE  CASE TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )
       WHEN 0 THEN b.Monday
       WHEN 1 THEN b.Tuesday
       WHEN 2 THEN b.Wednesday
       WHEN 3 THEN b.Thursday
       WHEN 4 THEN b.Friday
       WHEN 5 THEN b.Saturday
       WHEN 6 THEN b.Sunday
       END                      BETWEEN 6 AND 23
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9ed5f/3/0)**:

```
| USER_ID | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY | SATURDAY | SUNDAY |
|---------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------|--------|
|       1 |      2 |       3 |         4 |        5 |      6 |        7 |      8 |
```

**Query 2**:
 You appear to just want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT c.USER_ID, 
       b.monday,
       b.tuesday,
       b.wednesday,
       b.thursday, 
       b.friday,
       b.saturday,
       b.sunday
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN table3 c
       ON ( a.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b 
       ON ( c.USER_ID = b.USER_ID )
WHERE  b.USER_ID IS NULL
OR     NOT (
         CASE TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )
         WHEN 0 THEN b.Monday
         WHEN 1 THEN b.Tuesday
         WHEN 2 THEN b.Wednesday
         WHEN 3 THEN b.Thursday
         WHEN 4 THEN b.Friday
         WHEN 5 THEN b.Saturday
         WHEN 6 THEN b.Sunday
         END                      BETWEEN 6 AND 23
       )
OR     CASE TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )
       WHEN 0 THEN b.Monday
       WHEN 1 THEN b.Tuesday
       WHEN 2 THEN b.Wednesday
       WHEN 3 THEN b.Thursday
       WHEN 4 THEN b.Friday
       WHEN 5 THEN b.Saturday
       WHEN 6 THEN b.Sunday
       END                        IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9ed5f/3/1)**:

```
| USER_ID | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY | SATURDAY | SUNDAY |
|---------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------|--------|
|       2 | (null) |  (null) |    (null) |   (null) | (null) |   (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks @MTO, With list 2, this doesn't include the case where the user is not in Table 2 correct?

Comment: @TM3 That is what a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is for.

Comment: @MTO, ah ok, that's new to me, I tried this and I'm getting a missing keyword error: "ORA-00905: missing keyword"

Comment: @TM3 Updated, there was an extra `JOIN` keyword that is now removed.